# Reload a ComboBox store on trigger click Extjs 3.4

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs3

I'm a beginner on `js` and ExtJS 3.4, I'm trying to use `Ext.form.ComboBox`in a Ext.window to show the list of `js` objects (layers).

The problem is when I create the window the first time and I click on the `combobox` trigger I get my layers list correctly, but when I remove or add a layer and I click again on the trigger the store don't update and I find the same list.

Can you please help me to find a solution to this problem, for example when I click on the trigger it will update and load the new list store ?

Any suggestion is welcome.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
// The "ImageField" is an item witch is called on the return of the methode "createWindow" ...
createWindow: function() {

    ImageField = new Ext.form.ComboBox(Ext.apply({
        name: "Image_ref",
        fieldLabel: "Image Input (Required)",
        emptyText: "Select your Image",
        xtype: 'combo',
        forceSelection: true,
        editable: true,
        allowBlank: true,
        triggerAction: 'all',
        mode: 'local',
        valueField: 'value',
        displayField: 'text',
        labelWidth: 300
        width: 250,
        id: 'myCombo',
        hideLabel: false,
        lazyRender: false,
        lazyInit: false,
        mode: 'local',
        triggerAction: 'all',


        store: new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
            autoLoad: true,
            autoDestroy: true,
            fields: ['text', 'value'],
            data: layer_liste_WCS // is a liste of js objects
        }),
        listeners: {

            beforequery: function(qe) {
                // console.log(qe);
                qe.cancel = true;
                addComboxFieldItemsWCS(); // Run this methode to get "layer_liste_WCS" witch is liste of data
                var actionComboBox = Ext.getCmp('myCombo');
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                // I don't know how to do to reload the store after runing the methode "addComboxFieldItemsWCS"
            }
        }

    }, base));

    return new Ext.Window({
        closable: true,
        resizable: false,
        shadow: false,
        closeAction: 'hide',
        region: "center", //"north","south","east","west"
        width: 480,
        height: 190,
        iconCls: 'wind_icon',
        plain: true,
        layout: 'border',
        buttonAlign: 'right',
        layout: 'fit',
        listeners: {
            show: function() {
                this.el.setStyle('left', '');
                this.el.setStyle('top', '');
            }
        },
        items: [{
            region: 'center',
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            activeTab: 0,
            width: 50,
            height: 20,
            items: [{ // we will declare 3 tabs
                title: 'Datas Inputs',
                closable: false,
                iconCls: 'input_icon',
                active: true,
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'form',
                    autoWidth: true,
                    labelWidth: 185,
                    bodyStyle: "padding:10px;",
                    items: [
                        ImageField,
                    ]
                }]
            }]
        }],
    });
},
```

Comment: How are you removing\adding layers to your store? Can you share that code

Comment: Hear is the page : http://geoxxx.agrocampus-ouest.fr/mapfishapp/?lang=en&wmc=http%3A%2F%2Fgeoxxx.agrocampus-ouest.fr%2Fmapfishapp%2Fws%2Fwmc%2Fgeodocc82c178e7cd5e379b1795526fdba2a15.wmc     To find the window go to "tools" -> "WPS Jussie"   and use the right panel to remove/add layers. here is the source code : https://github.com/geosas/wpsjussie/blob/master/js/main.js

Answer (score 0):

I'm late for the answer but I take a chance.

Do you have an ajax call in `addComboxFieldItemsWCS`?

Put this code on your callback if you can:

```
Ext.getCmp('myCombo').getStore().loadData(layer_liste_WCS, false);
```

For your information, The false parameter is to replace existing data.

Hope this help.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry to be late !

No ! I don't have an Ajax call !
The store is an array of a ['text', 'value'].
can you please post an exemple code ?

Thank you in advance !